# How to add btorfs multiselect placeholder change default text Select to Select Country?

Tags: angularjs, multi-select

Please give me solution how to add placeholder in  btorfs multiselect Angular js?

My Coding.

```
 <multiselectdrop ng-model="blogadd.country" options="countryList"  display-prop="country_name" search-limit="countryListCount" id-prop="country_name" show-select-all="true" show-unselect-all="true" name="country" header-text="Select Stuff1" required ng-change="check_blogcountry(blogadd.country)">
                            </multiselectdrop>
```

Am checked header-text and header it's not Working,Once i add header means got error like below,

```
multiselect] asking for template on: <header  got error like these

(function () {
'use strict';

   var multiselect = angular.module('btorfs.multiselect',     ['btorfs.multiselect.templates']);

multiselect.getRecursiveProperty = function (object, path) {
    return path.split('.').reduce(function (object, x) {
        if (object) {
            return object[x];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }, object)
};

   multiselect.directive('multiselectdrop', ['$filter', '$document', '$log', '$interval', function ($filter, $document, $log, $interval) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            options: '=',
            displayProp: '@',
            idProp: '@',
            searchLimit: '=?',
            selectionLimit: '=?',
            showSelectAll: '=?',
            showUnselectAll: '=?',
            showSearch: '=?',
            searchFilter: '=?',
            disabled: '=?ngDisabled'
        },
           require: 'ngModel',
      templateUrl: 'multiselect.html',
      link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $ngModelCtrl) {
            $scope.selectionLimit = $scope.selectionLimit || 0;
            $scope.searchLimit = $scope.searchLimit ;

            $scope.searchFilter = '';

            if (typeof $attrs.disabled != 'undefined') {
                $scope.disabled = true;
            }

            $scope.toggleDropdown = function () {
                $scope.open = !$scope.open;
            };

            var closeHandler = function (event) {
                if (!$element[0].contains(event.target)) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.open = false;
                    });
                }
            };

            $document.on('click', closeHandler);

            var updateSelectionLists = function () {
                if (!$ngModelCtrl.$viewValue) {
                    if ($scope.selectedOptions) {
                        $scope.selectedOptions = [];
                    }
                    $scope.unselectedOptions = angular.copy($scope.resolvedOptions);
                } else {
                    $scope.selectedOptions = $scope.resolvedOptions.filter(function (el) {
                        var id = $scope.getId(el);
                        for (var i = 0; i < $ngModelCtrl.$viewValue.length; i++) {
                            var selectedId = $scope.getId($ngModelCtrl.$viewValue[i]);
                            if (id === selectedId) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                    $scope.unselectedOptions = $scope.resolvedOptions.filter(function (el) {
                        return $scope.selectedOptions.indexOf(el) < 0;
                    });
                }
            };

            $ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
                updateSelectionLists();
            };

            $ngModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(function () {
                updateSelectionLists();
            });

            $ngModelCtrl.$isEmpty = function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    return (value.length === 0);
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            var watcher = $scope.$watch('selectedOptions', function () {
                $ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(angular.copy($scope.selectedOptions));
            }, true);

            $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                $document.off('click', closeHandler);
                if (watcher) {
                    watcher(); // Clean watcher
                }
            });

            $scope.getButtonText = function () {
                if ($scope.selectedOptions && $scope.selectedOptions.length === 1) {
                    return $scope.getDisplay($scope.selectedOptions[0]);
                }
                if ($scope.selectedOptions && $scope.selectedOptions.length > 1) {
                    var totalSelected;
                    totalSelected = angular.isDefined($scope.selectedOptions) ? $scope.selectedOptions.length : 0;
                    if (totalSelected === 0) {
                        return 'Select';
                    } else {
                        return totalSelected + ' ' + 'selected';
                    }
                } else {
                    return 'Select';
                }
            };

            $scope.selectAll = function () {
                $scope.selectedOptions = $scope.resolvedOptions;
                $scope.unselectedOptions = [];
            };

            $scope.unselectAll = function () {
                $scope.selectedOptions = [];
                $scope.unselectedOptions = $scope.resolvedOptions;
            };

            $scope.toggleItem = function (item) {
                if (typeof $scope.selectedOptions === 'undefined') {
                    $scope.selectedOptions = [];
                }
                var selectedIndex = $scope.selectedOptions.indexOf(item);
                var currentlySelected = (selectedIndex !== -1);
                if (currentlySelected) {
                    $scope.unselectedOptions.push($scope.selectedOptions[selectedIndex]);
                    $scope.selectedOptions.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
                } else if (!currentlySelected && ($scope.selectionLimit === 0 || $scope.selectedOptions.length < $scope.selectionLimit)) {
                    var unselectedIndex = $scope.unselectedOptions.indexOf(item);
                    $scope.unselectedOptions.splice(unselectedIndex, 1);
                    $scope.selectedOptions.push(item);
                }
            };

            $scope.getId = function (item) {
                if (angular.isString(item)) {
                    return item;
                } else if (angular.isObject(item)) {
                    if ($scope.idProp) {
                        return multiselect.getRecursiveProperty(item, $scope.idProp);
                    } else {
                        $log.error('Multiselect: when using objects as model, a idProp value is mandatory.');
                        return '';
                    }
                } else {
                    return item;
                }
            };

            $scope.getDisplay = function (item) {
                if (angular.isString(item)) {
                    return item;
                } else if (angular.isObject(item)) {
                    if ($scope.displayProp) {
                        return multiselect.getRecursiveProperty(item, $scope.displayProp);
                    } else {
                        $log.error('Multiselect: when using objects as model, a displayProp value is mandatory.');
                        return '';
                    }
                } else {
                    return item;
                }
            };

            $scope.isSelected = function (item) {
                if (!$scope.selectedOptions) {
                    return false;
                }
                var itemId = $scope.getId(item);
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
                    var selectedElement = $scope.selectedOptions[i];
                    if ($scope.getId(selectedElement) === itemId) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            };

            $scope.updateOptions = function () {
                if (typeof $scope.options === 'function') {
                    $scope.options().then(function (resolvedOptions) {
                        $scope.resolvedOptions = resolvedOptions;
                        updateSelectionLists();
                    });
                }
            };

            // This search function is optimized to take into account the search limit.
            // Using angular limitTo filter is not efficient for big lists, because it still runs the search for
            // all elements, even if the limit is reached
            $scope.search = function () {
                var counter = 0;
                return function (item) {
                    if (counter > $scope.searchLimit) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    var displayName = $scope.getDisplay(item);
                    if (displayName) {
                        var result = displayName.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchFilter.toLowerCase()) > -1;
                        if (result) {
                            counter++;
                        }
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            };


            $interval(function(){
                $scope.resolvedOptions = $scope.options;
                updateSelectionLists();
            },2000);

            $scope.resolvedOptions = [];
            if (typeof $scope.options !== 'function') {
                $scope.resolvedOptions = $scope.options;
            } else {
                $scope.updateOptions();
            }

        }
    };
}]);
```

}());

```
 angular.module('btorfs.multiselect.templates', ['multiselect.html']);

angular.module("multiselect.html", []).run(["$templateCache",      function($templateCache) {
 $templateCache.put("multiselect.html",
 "<div class=\"btn-group\" style=\"width: 100%\">\n" +
"    <button type=\"button\" class=\"form-control btn btn-default btn-block dropdown-toggle\" ng-click=\"toggleDropdown()\" ng-disabled=\"disabled\">\n" +
"        {{getButtonText()}}&nbsp;<span class=\"caret\"></span>\n" +
"    </button>\n" +
"    <ul class=\"dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form\"\n" +
"        ng-style=\"{display: open ? 'block' : 'none'}\" style=\"width: 100%; overflow-x: auto\">\n" +
"\n" +
"        <li ng-show=\"showSelectAll\">\n" +
"            <a ng-click=\"selectAll()\" href=\"\">\n" +
"                <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></span> Select All\n" +
"            </a>\n" +
"        </li>\n" +
"        <li ng-show=\"showUnselectAll\">\n" +
"            <a ng-click=\"unselectAll()\" href=\"\">\n" +
"                <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span> Unselect All\n" +
"            </a>\n" +
"        </li>\n" +
"        <li ng-show=\"(showSelectAll || showUnselectAll)\"\n" +
"            class=\"divider\">\n" +
"        </li>\n" +
"\n" +
"        <li role=\"presentation\" ng-repeat=\"option in selectedOptions\" class=\"active\">\n" +
"            <a class=\"item-selected\" href=\"\" ng-click=\"toggleItem(option); $event.stopPropagation()\">\n" +
"                <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span>\n" +
"                {{getDisplay(option)}}\n" +
"            </a>\n" +
"        </li>\n" +
"        <li ng-show=\"selectedOptions.length > 0\" class=\"divider\"></li>\n" +
"\n" +
"        <li ng-show=\"showSearch\">\n" +
"            <div class=\"dropdown-header\">\n" +
"                <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control input-sm\" style=\"width: 100%;\"\n" +
"                       ng-model=\"searchFilter\" placeholder=\"Search...\" ng-change=\"updateOptions()\"/>\n" +
"            </div>\n" +
"        </li>\n" +
"\n" +
"        <li ng-show=\"showSearch\" class=\"divider\"></li>\n" +
"        <li role=\"presentation\" ng-repeat=\"option in unselectedOptions | filter:search() | limitTo: searchLimit\"\n" +
"            ng-if=\"!isSelected(option)\"\n" +
"            ng-class=\"{disabled : selectionLimit && selectedOptions.length >= selectionLimit}\">\n" +
"            <a class=\"item-unselected\" href=\"\" ng-click=\"toggleItem(option); $event.stopPropagation()\">\n" +
"                {{getDisplay(option)}}\n" +
"            </a>\n" +
"        </li>\n" +
"\n" +
"        <li class=\"divider\" ng-show=\"selectionLimit > 1\"></li>\n" +
"        <li role=\"presentation\" ng-show=\"selectionLimit > 1\">\n" +
"            <a>{{selectedOptions.length || 0}} / {{selectionLimit}} selected</a>\n" +
"        </li>\n" +
"\n" +
"    </ul>\n" +
"</div>");
```

}]);

Attached My directive coding,Please give me solution how to add placeholder once user give assign default-text in directive call in html tags or else select tag

Answer (score 0):

I think template file loading failed or your template URL may be wrong.

Update your question with directive code others can easily answer..

Comment: Thanx for your response,don't need to load template for me,Without template how to add placeholder

Comment: Am using js <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap-multiselect/dist/angular-bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script> not using directive

Comment: did you mentioned(dependency injection) multi select module name in main module..   var app = angular.module('myApp', ['theAboveJSfileModuleName']);              multiselectdrop is directive only. you just go through the document where you get the source.

Comment: Am refer this url https://bentorfs.github.io/angular-bootstrap-multiselect/ angular.module('myApp', [btorfs.multiselect']); add like these,Sry am new to angular js,sry for your inconvenience.But in these url am add js and css file and that app include.

Comment: Better try this..http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/. Demo - http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/demo-multiple-selection.html

Comment: Is there no option to change default text when no option selected in btorfs.multiselect?

Comment: simply you can give text in placeholder="Not yet selected"

Comment: No it's not working it will try default-text = "Select Country"  its also not working.

Comment: did you got any erroe in console